# BuildConfig Failure error ';' expected

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, buildconfig

I am importing the project: https://github.com/Kennyc1012/OpenImgur
and after receiving Imgurs Client ID and API Client Secret, bulding the project is fine, but then attempting to run the app notes the errors:

[image]

Within the BuildConfig.java file:

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.kennyc.open.imgur";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 21;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "2.6.2";
  // Fields from default config.
  public static final String API_CLIENT_ID = fd8drdsgdsgsd4;
  public static final String API_CLIENT_SECRET = 5d4f9adab5zdfhfdxzxdfbdbc72a18087ce;
}
```

I had placed the API Client ID and Client Secret just as noted in the `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kennyc1012/maven' }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven" }
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2" // 22.0.1

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kennyc.open.imgur"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 21
        versionName "2.6.2"
        buildConfigField "String", "API_CLIENT_ID", "fd8drdsgdsgsd4"
        buildConfigField "String", "API_CLIENT_SECRET", "5d4f9adab5zdfhfdxzxdfbdbc72a18087ce"
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
            minifyEnabled false
            manifestPlaceholders = [fabric_key: ""]
        }

        debug {
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            minifyEnabled false
            manifestPlaceholders = [fabric_key: ""]
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

Yet error persists. Given the BuildConfig file is generated, why would this error occur?

Comment: Why are you adding your API keys in the generated `BuildConfig`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your `BuildConfig.java`, these `Strings` need to have quotes:

```
public static final String API_CLIENT_ID = "fd8drdsgdsgsd4";
public static final String API_CLIENT_SECRET = "5d4f9adab5zdfhfdxzxdfbdbc72a18087ce";
```

The original project on Github looks like this:

```
buildConfigField "String", "API_CLIENT_ID", project.API_CLIENT_ID
buildConfigField "String", "API_CLIENT_SECRET", project.API_CLIENT_SECRET
```

The `project.` means that `API_CLIENT_ID` and `API_CLIENT_SECRET` are defined in a `gradle.properties` file. (This is not located in the repo).

I would create a `gradle.properties` and put in the same directory as the `build.gradle`, something like this:

```
API_CLIENT_ID = fd8drdsgdsgsd4
API_CLIENT_SECRET = 5d4f9adab5zdfhfdxzxdfbdbc72a18087ce
FABRIC_KEY = some key
```

The project is written to just easily swap out the variables with your own `gradle.properties`.

Comment: I have attempted to hard code in the BuildConfig.java file, but it always writes over at runtime

Comment: How can I add `gradle.propertles` file to the app, properly?

Comment: @Sauron Please see my answer, I said `I would create a gradle.properties and put in the same directory as the build.gradle`.

Comment: How would that be accomplished?

Comment: @Sauron It is just an empty file. What you are you asking? Just create an empty text file and copy and paste my answer in it.

Comment: Ok, it got pass the other point, now another error, thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76317/discussion-between-sauron-and-jared-burrows).

Comment: Hello Jared I have another question, about user auto login and services: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932349/allowing-service-time-to-start-up

Answer (score 14):

Try adding single quote like this :

```
buildConfigField "String", "API_CLIENT_ID", '"fd8drdsgdsgsd4"'
buildConfigField "String", "API_CLIENT_SECRET", '"5d4f9adab5zdfhfdxzxdfbdbc72a18087ce"'
```

Adding a single quote will keep the double quotes intact after BuildConfig class generation

Comment: The Idea of adding single quotes around double quotes is great. Thank you for this simple tricky answer

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone faces the same problem as me, where adding single quote didn't work. I used backslash `\` as an escape character within a string value.

```
buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"{YOUR_BASE_URL}\"")
buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", "\"{YOUR_API_KEY}\"")
```